# Lightswitch 2013 - HTML Client -> commitChanges() and showOtherPage() in union

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

just thought id ask on here as this is driving me insane... what im trying to do is `commitChanges()` or `applyChanges()`, followed my a `myapp.showBrowseOtherScreen()`

this is the way im trying to do it:

```
var result = confirm("Send Parcel?");
if (result == true) {
    screen.ProjectFinance.SendParcel = true;
    myapp.showBrowseInvoices();
}
else {
    msls.showMessageBox("Application Not Sent", { title: "Aborted" });
    myapp.cancelChanges();
    screen.ProjectFinance.SendParcel = false;
}
};
```

what it does currently is displays the message "Send Parcel", if i click OK, then it then brings up another option, as now that SendParcel has been set to true, there are unsaved changes on the page...

I need it to save and then navigate but im not sure what to try next, thanks for any help or advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save(), saveChanges(), and commitChanges() are all asynchronous. So it starts the save operation, then tries to navigate away before the save is completed.

```
myapp.commitChanges().then(function () {
    myapp.showBrowseInvoices();
}
```

The .then method takes up to two parameters. both functions, which can be defined in line like the example above, or calls to functions defined elsewhere. The first parameter is executed after successful completion of the operation, and the second is after failure.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to call a Save() on the entity after the Send Parcel change before opening up the next screen.  :)

Comment: ive tried myapp.CommitChanges() and myapp.SaveChanges() along with myapp.ShowBrowseInvoices() and still with no joy

Comment: Okay - what about myapp.SaveChanges() followed by a screen refresh on the active screen?

Comment: ive tried that previously aswell, when I implemented the save then refresh in, its as if its calling both at the same time... because it causes it to crash